# Loading content from textarea when in view

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, blogs

I'm building a blog-like portfolio. I want the content of the posts to be loaded only when they are viewed. To do that I tried to store the HTML code in a textarea in the meantime and place it in a div when the post is viewed. This works fine but for some reason the content is not recognized as HTML when placed in the div.

Can anyone tell me why?

You can find the testpage here: http://www.raapwerk.nl/login/portfolio

Thanks!

Comment: What is being sent to the DIV? Have you checked that the HTML code has changed? Could you put this into a fiddle?

Comment: Not really familiar with jsfiddle, but I think here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/sXLcu/

Comment: Basically I do this when the post comes in to view. But the content in the textarea is loaded as text and not as HTML..

Comment: And just for clarity ;) I need it to be loaded as HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `textarea` contains text, no HTML, so when you copy the contents it will be plain text you're copying. Is there any specific reason you use a `textarea`?

Otherwise you can just change it to a `div` and it will work, see [this update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXLcu/1/)

---

**EDIT**

Easier method, which doesn't load the content before it is displayed: just get the `value` of the textarea instead of the `innerHtml`, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXLcu/5/)

Comment: The reason for using a textarea is that I don't want the content to load just yet. I only want the content to load when the post is into view. Is there maybe another way to store the HTML somewhere in the meantime (preferably without ajax)?

Comment: Does the content only contain images? In that case you can change the `src` attribute with a `data-src` attribute and replace it when you copy the contents see http://jsfiddle.net/sXLcu/4/ . The image won't load because the src attribute is empty, until you press the button.

Comment: Scratch that, see updated answer, just get the `value` of the textarea